# how to open eap file

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

I am trying to open the .eap file, but I cannot. 
I receive this message:
"one or more version control configurations used by this model are not fully defined on this machine".

Do you know how I can fix this problem?

Best Regards
Murtaza

Answer (score 3):

This means that there are version controlled packages in the model and the configuration to the version control working copy is not fully defined for this machine.

I guess that you have copied a project that was version controlled in the machine you copied from, and now you have to configure the version control paths to the working copy on YOUR machine.

What you should do is to click "No" when you are asked of to complete the configuration now, then the EAP is opened.

Then click in `Project on the main menu -> version control -> version control settings`, there you can browse to the local path to your version control working copy, for each configuration.

When this is done, from now on, no problem will occur while opening EA projects.